# Management of CVK key in Key Block format

Tags: encryption, key, hsm, payment

I use a Thales PayShield 10K with a LMK KeyBlock 3DES. I have to send a CVK Key to a Scheme for the valorization of CVV2 value. Now, in my envorinment i generated a CVK Key with "Key Usage"= C0 and encrypted it under a ZMK (Key scheme "s").

About the problem: the Scheme sent the documentation related to the cvk exchange and mentions "a pair of single keys a+b in hexadecimal format". I know that was the standard for Variant keys, how can i manage this type of Key when i use a Key Block LMK?

I was suggested to use Key Scheme X when exporting. What is the technical reason?